# I want to append error message on div element

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a sign-in page. I am currently busy with validation part in JS.

What I wan to know, if this is the correct way in doing it.

I did a logic that says if username is not entered error message should appear below the username stating `Please add your username`.

This is how I did the HTML element and js logic

HTML

```
<div class="container">

            <form action="" class="form">

            <div class="heading">
                <h1>Log In</h1>
                <p>Welcome to your finacial smart decision making</p>
            </div>
        
            <div class="row mb-3 align-item-center">
                <label for="formGroupEampleInput" class="form-label" id="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="User Name" required>
                <div class="username-error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3 align-item-center">
                <label for="formGroupEampleInput" class="form-label" id="password">Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Password" required>
                <div class="password-error"></div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick ="validate()">Login</button>
        </form>

        <div class="side-image-container">

        </div>
```

JS

```
function validate(){

let username = document.querySelector("#username");
let password = document.querySelector("#username");
let usernameError = document.querySelector(".username-error");;
const createdEl = document.createElement("div");

 createdEl = document.createTextNode("Please add your username");

 if(!username){
    createdEl.appendChild(usernameError);
 }
}
```

[image: Indication where the error message should apepar]

Comment: You may want to consider another option, like having a node that you can fill the contents of instead of appending a node. In your current scenario, if a user kept clicking the button, more nodes would continue to be appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let username = document.querySelector("#username");
let password = document.querySelector("#username");
let usernameError = document.querySelector(".username-error");;
let createdEl = document.createElement("div");

let createdE2 = document.createTextNode("Please add your username");

createdEl.appendChild(createdE2);

 if(!username.value){
    usernameError.appendChild(createdEl);
 }
}
```

Use this instead

Comment: why is this any different?

Comment: Thank you, I see what you did there. I was missing the value of the username input and did not give the ```createTextNode``` a variable and ```createdEl.appendChild(createdE2)``` So thank you @rishabh

Comment: It will add div but needs extra check if there is already a div exists as a child of usernameError 
if exists : no need to appendChild
else : append child

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would recommend you using id instead of class to get querySelector, because, with id you will get a single element. but with class you may get list of elements.

After, I think you are appending in wrong way the child, you should do next:

```js
usernameError.appendChild(usernameError);
```

Or you can use innerHtml.

The best way to do that:

Normally, if you have a fixed text to show or hide, you don’t need to create it dynamically and append to a div.

You can create a class to hide it.

html:

```html
<div class="username-error hide">
  Please add your username
</div>
```

css:

```css
.hide{
    display:none;  
}
```

So, when you want to show the error just remove this class from your error element (div), otherwise add it.

js:

```js
if(!username){
  element.classList.remove("hide");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. `username` and `password` id is set on `<label>` element, not `<input>`
2. `validate()` function is trying assign a `textNode` element to a constant
3. you are trying to append existing `.username-error` element to a newly created `textElement` instead of vise-versa
4. when error printed there is no way remove the error
5. since your `error` placeholder element contains just text, you don't need create `textNode`, you can simply change the text via `textContent` property.

Here is simplified version that fixes all the above:

```js
function validate(){

let username = document.querySelector("#username");
let password = document.querySelector("#password");
let usernameError = document.querySelector(".username-error");;
let passwordError = document.querySelector(".password-error");;

usernameError.textContent = username.value == "" ? "Please add your username" : "";
passwordError.textContent = password.value == "" ? "Please add your password" : "";

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

            <form action="" class="form">

            <div class="heading">
                <h1>Log In</h1>
                <p>Welcome to your finacial smart decision making</p>
            </div>
        
            <div class="row mb-3 align-item-center">
                <label for="formGroupEampleInput" class="form-label">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="username" placeholder="User Name" required>
                <div class="username-error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3 align-item-center">
                <label for="formGroupEampleInput" class="form-label" >Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                <div class="password-error"></div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick ="validate()">Login</button>
        </form>

        <div class="side-image-container">

        </div>
```